# filter an xml / datagridview vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview

I have an xml file which I read into a datagrid such as follows:

```
Dim AuthorsDataSet As New DataSet
Dim filePath As String = "C:\test\courses.xml"

AuthorsDataSet.ReadXml(filePath)

DataGridView1.DataSource = AuthorsDataSet
DataGridView1.DataMember = "Lesson"
```

This works fine, however I want to incorperate a filltering of my datagridview1, searching based apon what is typed in textbox4 but I am totaly lost at what to do. I found the following site [CLICK HERE TO VIEW](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/FilterData.htm) but now im having to deal with tables and the likes wich i have no idea towards.

Could somebody help me out?

Comment: That link is fine, whats the problem?

Comment: Yes the link works I'm sure it dose, but that's for a situation where the datagridview has associated tables, I have none so it dosnt work and I cant findout how to get/ create these tables.

Comment: You have a dataset dont you, that will contain tables...

Comment: Dim datatableyourelookingfor as Datatable = datagridview1.datasource